# Kayak options in Patagonia

Tags: rental, chile, outdoor-activities, patagonia, canoeing-and-kayaking

We'll be traveling to Patagonia (Chilean side) and staying there for about a week. We're very interested in undertaking a kayak trip when down there. However, so far I only found offers from tour operators that include kayaking packages that are quite expensive (2 days, $995 per person, that kind of pricing). We are a quite independent group of 5 and look for an alternative. We do not need a totally arranged tour. We are more interested in just renting the kayaks and heading out for 4-5 days in the kayak. If recommended, together with a guide. We do not care too much about sleeping comfort and are okay with not being able to cover the most awesome places or have the most convenience during the trip. We very much like to hire some kayaks from a local family and contract one of their family members to be our guide, than to go with a tour operator. Is something like this possible? Any recommendations as to how to find this?

Our starting point will be Punta Arenas.

Comment: Sea kayak or river?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.patagonianexpeditionrace.com/ includes kayak hire and appears to be cheaper than the price you have.  You could enter that.  Or you could ask them where they hire their kayaks from as it must be cheaper than what you have been quoted.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote them but was not able to get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know folks who have hired boats from Pucon Kayak Hostel for whitewater expeditions, they may be able to help you out, or at least put you in touch with someone

https://puconkayakhostel.com/